# How to import youtube video into premiere cs4

Tags: video, premiere, youtube

I installed adobe premiere cs4 and was really astonished by the fact that it's not possible to import a video downloaded from YouTube, but it is needed to convert it firstly. This application is weight about 3GB on my hard disk and now I must search for a plugin to import a video from YT.

It would be perfectly if i could download a video directly into premiere, and also upload finished file up to youtube.

The only result of my search is a paid plugin named moyea-importer - USD 70
Is there any free plugin for this task. Or any similar solution.
If not - in which format should I download youtube video, in which format should I convert it (what is the best converter for that) to make it editable in premiere.
Working on win xp sp3.
Thanks.

Comment: How exactly were you downloading youtube videos?  Youtube is a streaming video service.  I wasn't aware there was an option to download.  There are third party tools that will rip a Youtube stream to disk, but it is worth noting that, strictly speaking, most of those are against the Youtube TOS I believe.  Once you have an actual video file on your computer, Premiere is unlikely to have a problem opening it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really all that astonishing.  Youtube is a streaming media service and Premiere is a video editing suite designed to work with files on your local computer.  It isn't part of the function of Premiere to deal with streaming media or convert from a stream to a file or to stream content (though it can produce stream ready files).

To use a video from Youtube, you would first need to use a Youtube stream ripper that will save it out as an actual video file which Premiere should then have no problem opening.  When you finish your project, you would then export to a Youtube compatible format and upload the file to Youtube.  Adobe Media Encoder (which can be used for doing the rendering out of Premiere) actually has presets specifically for Youtube.

Answer (score 1):

Excuse me if I am assuming something that is incorrect.  It appears that you want to download some one else's hard work, modify it by removing any signs of ownership and the HTTPHostHeader, making it appear like you are the owner, and ran your own raw data thru Adobe.  Is that correct??

Being a Youtube channel owner, I hate it when that happens.  Some one stealing your stuff and claiming it as their own...........

You may want to visit:    https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/youtube/categories

You can see what happens to people who are caught stealing some one else's work.

Other than that, try getting a video encoder from sourceforge and re encoding it first.  Then Adobe should be able to handle it.  I use Cyberlink Power Director 11 because it's smarter than Adobe, and will take anything you can feed it.

Sorry, I really dislike seeing people go against the YT terms of service and hurting other people on the way there.  I've seen a lot of channels terminated for doing just that kind of stuff.

Comment: That could be it, but there's also legitimate use cases IMO: commenting on someone else's video in your own video or embedding a few seconds of it for legit purposes like criticizing it. I see people on YouTube do it constantly, I think (assuming you are in the US) it falls under the fair use clause. Other countries have similar stuff. That said I have no idea what OP plans on doing.